# Download secure file with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I'm trying to create a new release task for VSTS which needs to download a [secure file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/library/secure-files) from the library. However, when I run the following PowerShell script no secure files are displayed but there are two in there. Could this be not having enough rights? What should be changed.

Another question: when I'm able to list the secure files I want to download a specific one. I haven't found any examples on how to do that. Does anyone know of an example?

```
$url = "$($env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI)$env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECTID/_apis/distributedtask/securefiles"

Write-Host "URL: $url"

$secureFiles = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{
    Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"
}
Write-Host "SecureFiles: $secureFiles"
```

Answer (score 6):

I was able to download Secure Files using a REST API, the task's Access Token, and an Accept header for application/octet-stream.  I enabled "Allow scripts to access the OAuth token".  Here my task.json is using a secureFile named "SecureFile."

```
$secFileId = Get-VstsInput -Name SecureFile -Require
$secTicket = Get-VstsSecureFileTicket -Id $secFileId
$secName = Get-VstsSecureFileName -Id $secFileId
$tempDirectory = Get-VstsTaskVariable -Name "Agent.TempDirectory" -Require
$collectionUrl = Get-VstsTaskVariable -Name "System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri" -Require
$project = Get-VstsTaskVariable -Name "System.TeamProject" -Require
$filePath = Join-Path $tempDirectory $secName

$token= Get-VstsTaskVariable -Name "System.AccessToken" -Require
$user = Get-VstsTaskVariable -Name "Release.RequestedForId" -Require

$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $User, $token)))
$headers = @{
    Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)
    Accept="application/octet-stream"
} 

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "$($collectionUrl)$project/_apis/distributedtask/securefiles/$($secFileId)?ticket=$($secTicket)&download=true&api-version=5.0-preview.1" -Headers $headers -OutFile $filePath
```

I am using "$(Build.QueuedById)" to get the user id in build tasks, but honestly I don't think it matters what string you use there.

If you don't have the Accept header, you'll get JSON metadata back for the file you're attempting to download.

Unfortunately I cobbled this together from other SO posts and the github issues pages; I can't find anywhere official that documents the URL I'm using there.

Comment: How did you get the ticket though?

Answer (score 4):

There has no such REST API to download secure file, but you can use **Download secure file task** for assistants.

And since the secure file only exist in temporary location during build, you should download the secure file by Download secure file task firstly, and copy the secure file to another directory secondly:

#### 1.   Download secure file

You can add a [Download secure file task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/utility/download-secure-file) (for VSTS) and specify the `filename` to download.

Note: since the task is not available for TFS, you can install the similar task like [Download Secure File](https://github.com/mlabrum/vsts-download-secure-file/issues/9) extension for your TFS account.

#### 2.   Copy secure file to another directory

Such as copy the secure file to `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`, you can use PowerShell script:

```
Copy-Item -Path $(Agent.WorkFolder)\_temp\filename -Destination $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
```

Or use Copy Files task to copy the secure file to `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`.

**BTW:**

- Since you are using Download Secure File task (developed by Matt Labrum) which can only select secure file from DropDownList (variables can not be used). But there has an issue [Enable to use a variable to specify the secure file to download](https://github.com/mlabrum/vsts-download-secure-file/issues/9) which suggests this feature, you can follow up.
- And for the REST API to download secure file, it's not available for now. But there has an user voice [Access "Secure files" from .NET client library](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/32752684-access-secure-files-from-net-client-library), and you can vote and follow up.

Comment: One of the problems with this task is that it doesn't allow me to use a variable as the name for the file. That means that when I clone my pipeline to another environment I have to do manual changes instead of adding a variable.

The task I'm trying to make is one that installs a certificate on my server. So it would be ideal to download and install the certificate in the same task and only download the certificate when it's not already installed.

Comment: The VSTS Node client seems to be having a downloadSecureFile function. The PowerShell one doesn't. Isn't that using the rest API?

https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-node-api

Comment: You can use a variable as the secure file name. What's the problem did you meet when you copy the secure file?

Comment: The task you mention doesn't seem to be available on TFS 2018 (on-premise)? So I'm using this one: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mattlabrum.build-task

Comment: Yes, the task is not available for TFS (I updated my answer). And I didn't aware that you use TFS not VSTS. But if the method in the answer helps you solve the problem, you can mark it as answer. And it will also benefit others who have similar questions.

Comment: I should have been more clear about TFS. Answer doesn't help since the problem I explained in my first comment to this answer remains.

Comment: Unfortunately, variables can not be used in download secure file task, and the REST API is also suggesting now. You can find related links in the end of my answer, and follow up the features.