# Dynamic Template using dynamic variable group causing an issue when downloading a Secure File

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines

I have a CI/CD Multistage template where my CD stages are dependent on a parameter I provide in a yaml file

Pipeline points to pipeline.yml

```
 servers:
  DEV:
  - srv-apimgmt37p
```

and in my template I have a loop that checks the servers and passes the value so it can dynamically produce my CI/CD pipeline depending on the above parameter. In my CD stage I have the following variable groups that I pass:

```
variables:
  - group: ${{ variables['Build.DefinitionName'] }}_MS_${{env.key}}
  - group: DevSecOps_${{ variables['Build.DefinitionName'] }}_MS_${{env.key}}
```

In one of those groups I have a variable which is the name of file that is stored in my secure files. Going back to my CD template, I have a Download Secure File task which will download the secure file using the name of the variable from the group called $(test)

```
- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
  displayName: 'Download kafka keytab'
  condition: "eq(ne(variables['test'], ''), true)"
  inputs:
    secureFile: "$(test)"
    retryCount: 5
```

The problem is that when the pipeline starts running, it tries to download the secure file first, but it cannot find it because it doesn't know yet the value of $(test). What should I do as a best practice in this scenario? I'm a little stuck on what a good solution would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to slap a parameter in my yaml file that resides in my repo. So in my template, I use the task as such

```
- ${{ if parameters.keytab[env.key] }}:
   - task: DownloadSecureFile@1
     name: kafkakeytab
     displayName: 'Download kafka keytab'
     inputs:
        secureFile: ${{parameters.keytab[env.key]}}
        retryCount: 5
```

and in my YAML file, I just reference a parameter as such:

```
keytab:
  DEV: bobbobob.keytab
  UAT: blablauat.keytab
```

This means that if I don't pass this parameter, the pipeline will not include the task in the pipeline, which is what I want. This way, I didn't have to create my own Powershell task to try to achieve this!

Answer (score 2):

`DownloadSecureFile` task is a pre-job. You may try use the powershell to download the Secure File as case [Download secure file with PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49175519/download-secure-file-with-powershell) mentioned.

> I was able to download Secure Files using a REST API, the task's
> Access Token, and an Accept header for application/octet-stream.  I
> enabled "Allow scripts to access the OAuth token".  Here my task.json
> is using a secureFile named "SecureFile."

```
$secFileId = Get-VstsInput -Name SecureFile -Require
$secTicket = Get-VstsSecureFileTicket -Id $secFileId
$secName = Get-VstsSecureFileName -Id $secFileId
$tempDirectory = Get-VstsTaskVariable -Name "Agent.TempDirectory" -Require
$collectionUrl = Get-VstsTaskVariable -Name "System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri" -Require
$project = Get-VstsTaskVariable -Name "System.TeamProject" -Require
$filePath = Join-Path $tempDirectory $secName

$token= Get-VstsTaskVariable -Name "System.AccessToken" -Require
$user = Get-VstsTaskVariable -Name "Release.RequestedForId" -Require

$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $User, $token)))
$headers = @{
    Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)
    Accept="application/octet-stream"
} 

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "$($collectionUrl)$project/_apis/distributedtask/securefiles/$($secFileId)?ticket=$($secTicket)&download=true&api-version=5.0-preview.1" -Headers $headers -OutFile $filePath
```

> I am using "$(Build.QueuedById)" to get the user id in build tasks,
> but honestly I don't think it matters what string you use there.
>
> If you don't have the Accept header, you'll get JSON metadata back for
> the file you're attempting to download.

Comment: Have you checked my reply? Is it helpful?